# In R Shiny, is there a way to test a selectizeInput length with javascript when it is inside a module

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, module

Here is a simple app : the button *show* should appear when the selectizeInput *choice* is not empty. I used a conditionalPanel with this simple JavaScript test : *"input.choice.length !== 0"*.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = 'choice', 
    label = NULL, 
    choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4"),
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = I("input.choice.length !== 0"),
    actionButton(inputId = 'show', label = "Show notif !")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    for (i in 1:length(input$choice)) {
      showNotification(input$choice[i])
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This app is working. But this will be part of a huge app and i try to modularize all this.

I first tried to put the conditionalPanel within the module file.

```r
# UI function
modFormUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = NS(id, 'choice'), 
      label = NULL, 
      choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4"),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = I("input.choice.length !== 0"),
      actionButton(inputId = NS(id, 'show'), label = "Show notif !")
    )
  )
}

# Server function
modFormServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      for (i in 1:length(input$choice)) {
        showNotification(input$choice[i])
      }
    })
  })
}


# App test
if (interactive()) {
  
  library(shiny)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    modFormUI('chooseZone')
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    modFormServer('chooseZone')
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

But it did'nt worked. I guess because of the name spaces. The name of the selectizeInput in the HTML page appears to be: *chooseZone-choice*.

My second approche was to put the conditionalPanel outside of the module. And to use the JavaScript condition *"input.chooseZone-choice.length !== 0"*.

```r
# UI function
modFormSelectUI <- function(id) {
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = NS(id, 'choice'), 
    label = NULL, 
    choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4"),
    multiple = TRUE
  )
}
modFormButtonUI <- function(id) {
  actionButton(inputId = NS(id, 'show'), label = "Show notif !")
}

# Server function
modFormServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      for (i in 1:length(input$choice)) {
        showNotification(input$choice[i])
      }
    })
  })
}

# App test
if (interactive()) {
  
  library(shiny)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    modFormSelectUI('chooseZone'),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = I("input.chooseZone-choice.length !== 0"),
      modFormButtonUI('chooseZone')
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    modFormServer('chooseZone')
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

But it didn't work..

I know this is a difficult one, but can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `ns` argument of `conditionalPanel`:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
    modFormSelectUI('chooseZone'),
    conditionalPanel(
      ns = NS("chooseZone"),
      condition = "input.choice.length !== 0",
      modFormButtonUI('chooseZone')
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, that's works !!

And for my example where the conditionPanel was within the module (my first idea) i can do :

```r
modFormUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = NS(id, 'choice'), 
      label = NULL, 
      choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4"),
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      ns = NS(id),
      condition = I("input.choice.length !== 0"),
      actionButton(inputId = NS(id, 'show'), label = "Show notif !")
    )
  )
}
```

Merci beaucoup Stéphane